# MagicalRecord saving takes time

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

i am using magicalrecord in my app to manage coredata, every thing is perfect now but i am having an issue,i created 10k entities using this code:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext * _Nonnull localContext) {

Person *person = [Person MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
person.organization = [Organization MR_findfirstInContext:localContext]; 
person.name = name;
person.id  = id;
person.age = age;

]};
```

after creating 10k records when i perform any change in database using magicalrecord it gets stuck for 4 or 5 seconds while saving to root context, which makes UI freez no matter if its on main thread or background thread.

**Edited:**
i have found the problem if i remove relation (which is organization) from save block it dont get stuck, if i fetch organization from out side the block and assign in inside the save block it throw an exception that organization is created in different context.

Comment: Why creating 10k entities should be fast? Just don't use a blocking call and show a progress indicator to the user.

Comment: no my question is not about creating fast , it is about if i have 10k entities or more saving to root context takes time.

Comment: You may want to create 10k entities, then save in that context, and not create 1 entity, save it in that context, and repeat 10k.

Comment: @Larme this is not the problem, i know if i want to create 10k entities i will use loop inside the magicalblock and it will save once, problem is having 10k or more entities in database then saving to root context takes time which freez UI

Answer (score 0):

```
//case A
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    NSLog(@"current thread is main thread %d and thread is %@", [NSThread isMainThread], [NSThread currentThread]);

    //some ManagedObject code
    ...
}];

//case B
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    NSLog(@"current thread is main thread %d and thread is %@", [NSThread isMainThread], [NSThread currentThread]);

    //some ManagedObject code
    ...
}];
```

test this code, you will find case A always run at the MainThread,if you have 10K entities to store, the UI get stuck.

[image]

Look at this https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Saving-Entities.md